# Método Recursivo LinkedList

Tags: java, recursão, lista-encadeada

Estou tendo dificuldades para a implementação de um método recursivo para o método de inserção de um elemento no final de uma lista simplesmente encadeada.

Segue abaixo o método Iterativo:

```
public void addLast(Node<E> novoNodo){
    if(isEmpty())
        addFirst(novoNodo);
    else{
        novoNodo.setNext(null);
        tail.setNext(novoNodo);
        tail = novoNodo;
        size++;
    }
}
```

No exercício que estou tentando realizar, preciso transformar este método em recursivo, porém não sei como posso realizar isto, visto que o método `last` não é um método com laços.

Comment: É estranho mesmo que seu `addLast` não tenha laços. Tem certeza que sua implementação está correta? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um exemplo para implementação para adicionar um valor de forma recursiva na sua lista simplesmente ligada seria:

```
    private Node lista;

    public void addLast(int valor)
    {
        addLast(lista, valor);
    }

    private void addLast(Node lista, int valor)
    {
        if (lista == null)
        {
            this.lista = new Node(valor, null);
        }
        else
        {
            if (lista.getNext() == null)
            {
                lista.setNext(new Node(valor, null));
            }
            else
            {
                addLast(lista.getNext(), valor);
            }
        }
    }
```

Primeiro você precisa ter o nodo inicial, e a partir dele você começa a percorrer para inserir no fim de sua lista simplesmente encadeada.

Comment: Hmmm entendi, um método auxiliar seria a solução no caso!

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda!!